# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Javascript breaks SelectedValue from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel and a DropDownList with some values on my page:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemDrop1 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItemDrop2 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItemDrop3 { get; set; }
    public List<OptionViewModel> Options { get; set; }
}

public class OptionViewModel
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }
}
```

And, into my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <ul id="cursos">
    <li>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedItemDrop1,
        new SelectList(Model.Options, "Number", "Option", Model.SelectedItemDrop1))
        Choose 1
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedItemDrop2,
        new SelectList(Model.Options, "Number", "Option", Model.SelectedItemDrop2))
        Choose 2
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedItemDrop3,
        new SelectList(Model.Options, "Number", "Option", Model.SelectedItemDrop3))
        Choose 3
    </li>
    </ul>
}
```

When I use Javascript to change options from these select elements, my return is null. What's the problem? Thank you so much!!!

EDIT:

My javascript code:

```
$("#cursos li select").each(function (i, item) {

    $(this).change(function () {
        updateCursos($(this), 7);
    });
    $(this).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});

function updateCursos(select, avaiableCourses) {

    var selecteds = '';
    $("#cursos li select").each(function (i, item) {
        var selected = $(item).val();
        if (selected != -1)
            selecteds += selected + ',';
    });

    var arr = selecteds.split(',');

    $("#cursos li select").each(function (i, item) {
        if ($(item).val() != select.val()) {

            var oldValue = $(item).val();
            if ($(item).val() == -1) {
                var options = "<option value='-1'></option>";
                for (i = 1; i <= avaiableCourses; ++i) {
                    if (select.val() != i && !contains(i, selecteds)) {
                        options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "ª option</option>";
                    }
                }
                options += "<option value='0'>Don't want it</option>";

                $(item).children("option").remove();
                $(item).html(options);
                $(item).val(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What JavaScript code do you use?

Comment: Just a jQuery code to remove some options and insert another options when I change a value into one of my selects. If I just disabled the option after change trigger, I get null into my ViewModel.

Comment: If the problem occurs only when you use this jQuery code, then it's likely the cause of your problem is in that code.

Comment: We need to see the javascript.

Comment: Well, my select options are based on a IList from my ViewModel. When I use the jQuery to add/remove options, I use the same values are generated by ViewModel. But it appears on POST my ViewModel is making some mistakes. Eg: my VM generates: "<option value='-1'></option>', and my jQuery codes generates the same option. So, why it causes problems?

Comment: Done, I've edited my topic with my javascript code!

Answer (score 0):

This way I'm sure that works, not even being javascript.

If the values ​​are not being filled are coming from the database, with fixed values ​​example: active, inactive, do the following

Create an enumerated type with these values

After the controller transforms this type enumerated in list using an internal class, turn it into a enumerable and go to the dropdownlist

example of usage:
@ Html.DropDownListFor (model => model.chamados.UrgenciaId, new SelectList (ViewBag.urgencia, "Id", "Name"))